# Stream a zip file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, azure-storage, filestream

I am searching for a solution to stream my zip file in order to send it through to azure blob-storage. 
Currently this is what I have

```
async _uploadStreamToBlob(zipFile, fileName) {
    const blobService = await this.__self.blobStorage.createBlobService(this.__self.blobStorageConnectionString);
    const containerName = this.__self.blobContainerName;

    const sourceFilePath = `${path.resolve(zipFile)}`;
    const streamSource = fs.createReadStream(sourceFilePath);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        streamSource.pipe(blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(containerName, fileName, error => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve({ message: `Upload of '${fileName}' complete` });
            }
        }));
    });
};
```

This clearly does not work as I've tested otherwise since the fileStream feeds zero bytes into the pipe, resulting in a succesful upload of a 0 byte zipFile into the blob-storage. 
How do I stream the zipFile onto the azureWriteStream? Or how do I get the bytes off of the zipFile(preserving the contents)?
If there is any other way to achieving this, I am all ears.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use createBlockBlobFromLocalFile directly:

```
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(containerName, fileName, sourceFilePath, (err) => {
    // Handle err
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, That was my first approach but it pushes 0 byte zip-file onto the blob. A simple text/xlsx file is uploaded without any hiccup but a zip-file not so much.